# How to do rounding

Tags: java, rounding

I want to calculate the bill where need to do some rounding

What i expect is:

it should be nearest 10 cents. e.g:

```
10.17 -> 10.20 (round up)

10.11 -> 10.10 (round down)
```

I have tried to use:

```
grandTotal = Double.valueOf(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.2f", grandTotal));
```

but it will occur error when the total look like 12.15, 14.65, 19.85.

By right, it should round up, but my result shows it round down.

Comment: Look into `Math.round()`

Comment: Never use `double` for monetary things. Use some integer type!

Comment: Not an Android problem

Comment: If you want rounding to just 1 decimal, you should use the format `%.1f` (not `%.2f`). Other than that, your code works nicely on my computer, also with 12.15 and 19.85 (they are rounded up to 12.2 and 19.9). What error are you seeing??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent monetary values with cents, you should only use integers (as cents), String or BigDecimal, not floats or doubles because floating-point values can't exactly represent all decimal values.

To round up to the first digit after comma, you can do:

```
BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal("10.17");
BigDecimal rounded = value.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, setScale rounds down by default, so the output of this snippet should be 10.1, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed, specifying the rounding mode is mandatory if the scale is reduced. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents for a possible solution:

```
Double value = 14.65;
Double grandTotal = Math.round(value * 10)/10;
```